# Are specific traffic comparisons on-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

I previously asked [Are questions about ideal travel/arrival times on-topic](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/are-questions-about-ideal-travel-arrival-times-on-topic) about trying to find the best arrival time to a specific location.

I have a semi-related follow up about comparing traffic in a different location to this location.  The general question is along the lines of

> Having endured the traffic problems arriving at *Location A* last summer, my family is considering other alternatives.  Since one of our alternative locations (*Location B*) has a similar road infrastructure, we are wondering if we should expect similar traffic delays upon arrival".

Would such a question be on-topic and are there specific recommendations to ensure I ask an answerable question.  It should be noted that the 2 locations are close enough together and popular summer vacation destinations that it is reasonable enough to expect someone to have visited both locations.

<sup>I generalized this question for purposes of meta, but the specific locations are both in the US (the Outer Banks in North Carolina, and Cape Code in Massachusetts)</sup>